# return strings starting with any of the characters in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to get all strings starting with any of the characters but it doesn't work in Snowflake. Can someone help if there is any way to do this

> select * from table where name LIKE '[A-E]%';

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rlike` instead of `like` and specify a regular expression:

```
select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.nation where n_name rlike '[A-E].*';
```

Use a regular expression wildcard, `.*` after the letters rather than a `like` wildcard, `%`.

For case insensitive searches, you have some options:

```
-- Second syntax of rlike specifying the 'i' parameter for case insensitivity.
select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.nation where rlike (n_name, '[a-e].*', 'i');

-- First syntax option changing the regular expression to find either upper or lower case.
select * from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1.nation where n_name rlike '[A-Ea-e].*';
```

Comment: this works, thank you. But, is there a way to do it case insensitive. Much appreciated.

Comment: Updated the answer with two options for case insensitivity using the first syntax of rlike (closer to the like function) or the second syntax (called like most functions).